# Como hago para almacenar datos en una bbdd un objeto que esta compuesto por otro desde consola

Tags: javascript, jsonobject

En postman me funciona bien, tengo un objeto compuesto por otro

```
{    "nombre" : "fie",
     "pocision" : {
        "latitud" : 1.6,
        "longitud" : 2.7
    } 
}
```

Lo que necesito es poder ingresarlo con `JS`. Claramente de la forma que tengo solo cargaría si longitud y latitud fueran datos del objeto organización.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
async function registrarOrganizacion(){

    let myOrg = {};
    myOrg.nombre = document.getElementById('txtNombre').value;
    myOrg.longitud = document.getElementById('txtLongitud').value;
    myOrg.latitud = document.getElementById('txtLatitud').value;

    const request = await fetch('organizacion', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body : JSON.stringify(myOrg)
    });
    console.log(request);
    alert("Se agregó a la Organizacion con exito!");
    window.location.href = 'organizaciones.html';
}
```

Comment: **Java != JavaScript**. Tanto [java] como [sql] no tienen relación con la pregunta, y [frontend] es una _meta-etiqueta_. _Bórralas_. Por otra parte: ¿estás mezclando JS "plano" con jQuery?

Comment: Cual es el problema de hacer `myOrg.posicion = { longitud: document.getElementById('txtLongitud').value, latitud: document.getElementById('txtLatitud').value };`?? Lo has intentado? Porque tal cual lo estás haciendo, obviamente no estás creando el objeto `posicion` si no que estás asignando latitud y longitud directamente al objeto padre... eso nunca va a crearte un objeto anidado claro.

Comment: Gracias, si no sabia como era la sintaxis, entendia que nunca creaba el objeto Posicion, ahora lo puse tal cual me pasaste, pero tampoco estaria pegando en la bbdd, debo tener algun otro problema.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear el objeto compuesto definiendo la propiedad 'posicion' como un objeto vacio:

```
    let myOrg = {
        posicion: {}
    };
    myOrg.nombre = document.getElementById('txtNombre').value;
    myOrg.posicion.longitud = document.getElementById('txtLongitud').value;
    myOrg.posicion.latitud = document.getElementById('txtLatitud').value;
```